# Why is the same Select parsed again on every execution if it contains a function from a different schema?

Tags: oracle, performance

In our application we have several queries that take a long time to parse (> 500 ms, sometimes much more) but are fast to execute (< 50 ms). This is due to complicated views and generally not a problem, if the parsed Query is cached by Oracle.

We now run into the problem that some Queries are parsed every time they are executed: These Queries select from a View in one Schema (SCHEMA1) and use a Function from a Package in a different Schema (SCHEMA2) in the Select clause.

When we execute this Query, it is parsed on every execution. In V$SQLAREA the VERSION_COUNT is equal to the number of executions. Every execution takes the long time.

If we warp the call to the Function from SCHEMA1 in a local Function in SCHEMA2 and use the new Function in the Query, only the first execution leads to a parse. All subsequent executions are much faster. In V$SQLAREA we see a VERSION_COUNT of 1 (or some number much lower than the number of executions).

Unfortunaly, wrapping the functions in local functions are highly impractical in our use case, because there are many functions in SCHEMA2 and they are used with Views von several other Schemas.

The Query doesn’t contain parameters and the circumstances of execution are exactly the same every time.

The effect dos not depend on the code in the function: if we replace the actual function with a test function that just returns a constant value, we get the same effect:

It doesn’t make a different whether we execute the Query from SCHEMA1, SCHEMA2 or any third Schema, except when we execute it as SYSDBA. In this case, subsequent executions don’t lead to new parses.

We use Oracle 12c Release 12.1.0.2.0.

Update: V$SQL_SHARED_CURSOR displays Y at AUTH_CHECK_MISMATCH for these queries. I am not sure yet what this means.

Comment: Is there Virtual Private Database/Row Level security involved? The query can be modified in the backround by these effectively producing unique command that requires new execution plan.

Comment: No, Row Level Security is not involved

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by various reasons.

- Different sql execution environment. For example caller uses different datatypes for bind variables. Check the view `V$SQL_SHARED_CURSOR`.
- Different optimizer goal
- Bind variable peeking. Check `v$sql.is_bind_aware`.
- Some bug in the database caused by `cursor_sharing` parameter

Maybe you should generate AWR and check wait events, and also the size of Library cache. Possibly Oracle might have problems to find some free space in Library cache for your query(is it's really complex).

Comment: The problem seems to be unrelated to bind parameters because it happens with queries without bind parameters.

Comment: You're right. So most of the reasons I describe are not valid. In 11g there is possibility to associate a PL/SQL function with statistics. Maybe 12c can possibly maintain function execution cost by it's own.

Comment: Thank you for the Tip to ceck V$SQL_SHARED_CURSOR. it displays Y at AUTH_CHECK_MISMATCH. I have to investigate waht that means. I also update the original Question